# dropdown menu issue on touchscreens

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu compatible with touch screen devices such as ipads.

On a pc it's fine, you hover over the menu you get the submenu, you hover over the submenu you get get the ...tertiary? menu.

However, on touch screens, you press the first menu and the secondary menu drops down. You press the secondary menu and everything hides away again.

Here's a codepen to show what I mean.

http://codepen.io/Fazy/pen/JWeaOW

Any ideas How I can fix the JS to implement this properly?

This is the JS I have...

```
        $('.dropdown').hover(
          function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('open')
          },
          function() {
            $(this).removeClass('open')
          }
        );

        $('.dropdown-submenu, .dropdown').click(
          function() {
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('stayopen')
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

That code-pen is no longer working so I'm guessing that the .`hover` and `.click` are somehow stepping on each others toes, because a touch event simulates a click event.

When you factor in touchscreen laptops, using hover drop-downs for touch devices gets fairly complicated.

If you're looking for a script to swap classes for hover and touch and to have it work for all devices, I wrote a jQuery plugin and article that goes into more detail about what is going on in the browser.

http://fallingmonocle.com/monocle-toggle.php

Hopefully that helps with what you are trying to achieve.